# how to lock for a variety of threads pthread_mutex_lock

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

how do you create a lock that would lock different threads from entering the function? 
Thread 1: A
Thread 2: C
Thread 3: C
Thread 4: B
Thread 5: C
Thread 6: B

"A", "B" ,"C" are the argument passed in to the thread when it is created.

so when I lock this one lock X, all threads of that have "A" and "B" passed in cannot continue and only thread of type "C" can enter the critical section. Or do I have to make 6 different locks for this example?

Thank you!

Comment: 3 lock: A, B, C. In case you only want C pass, lock A & B, enter critical section by try lock. And you are not mentioning about order, so maybe global variable is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement's vague, but assuming you want concurrent readers with the same "allowed letter", you'd be better off using a rwlock.  (If you actually just want a "control" thread to be setting which of A, B or C is allowed to work, rather than having A, B and C take over whenever no other "letter" is running through the controlled code, then a different (simpler) solution is needed....)

As a first cut (so we can "evolve" a solution in an easier-to-understand way), each thread:

1) acquires a reader lock

2) if the "allowed letter" variable differs from their letter, they release the reader lock and try for a writer lock

2a) when getting a writer lock, they modify the allowed letter to their own, then release that lock and restart at 1) (see below)

3) do their work

4) release the reader lock

This uses the "writer" mode to affect a change in allowed letter.  If you actually need to arbitrate some "allowed letter" threads having write access to the shared data, you will want to change 3) to take either a reader or writer lock on a *distinct* rwlock, to be released before 4).

2a) creates a race condition, in say an A thread gets the writer lock then sets the allowed letter, when it releases the lock a B thread may get a writer lock before it can get a reader lock to do some actual work.  The B thread may then release the writer lock and go for a reader lock only to find A now has it, so neither thread progresses, but nor are they deadlocked per se.  Whether this resolves itself depends primarily on the thread queuing implementation for the rwlock, but also on race conditions, interrupts, pre-emption due to system load etc..  This could be tackled in a couple ways, but it's easy and probably adequate to use an extra mutex to disallow other threads with write locks from modifying the allowed letter: they could use a trylock on this, and if it fails then release their write lock and restart at 1).

So, we end up with one or two rwlocks and a supporting mutex....